# Java Rational Lab

Tags: java

I cant seem to figure out what's wrong with my code.  I commented out the reduce() method to see if it would work with the unreduced fractions (I don't think my reduce() works) and for the first ones it does work, but when it gets to double digits and the later ones I cant figure out why it isn't working.

```
public class Rational implements Comparable<Rational> {
private int numerator, denominator;

public Rational() { numerator = 1; denominator = 1; }
public Rational(int num, int denom) { numerator = num; denominator = denom; }

public void setRational(int num, int denom) { setNumerator(num); setDenominator(denom); }
public void setNumerator(int num) { numerator = num; }
public void setDenominator(int denom) { denominator = denom; }

public int getNumerator() { return numerator; }
public int getDenominator() { return denominator; }

public void reduce() {
    setNumerator(this.numerator / gcd(this.numerator, this.denominator));
    setDenominator(this.denominator / gcd(this.numerator, this.denominator));
}
public int gcd(int num1, int num2) {
    if (num2 == 0) return num1;
    return gcd(num2,num1 % num2);
}

public Object clone() { return new Rational(getNumerator(), getDenominator()); }
public boolean equals(Object obj){ return this.compareTo((Rational)obj) == 0; }

public void add(Rational other) {
    this.setNumerator( (this.getNumerator() * other.denominator ) + ( other.numerator * this.getDenominator() ));
    this.setDenominator( this.getDenominator() * other.denominator );
    //reduce();
}

public void sub(Rational other) {
    numerator = ( this.getNumerator() * other.getDenominator() ) - ( other.getNumerator() * this.getDenominator() );
    denominator = ( this.getDenominator() * other.getDenominator() );
    //reduce();
}

public void mult(Rational other) {
    numerator = ( this.getNumerator() * other.getNumerator() );
    denominator = ( this.getDenominator() * other.getDenominator() );
    //reduce();
}

public void div(Rational other) {
    numerator = (this.getNumerator() * other.getDenominator());
    denominator = (this.getDenominator() * other.getNumerator());
    //reduce();
}

public int compareTo(Rational other) {
    reduce();
    other.reduce();

    if ( this.getDenominator() < other.getDenominator() ) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if ( this.getDenominator() == other.getDenominator() ) {
        if( this.getNumerator() < other.getNumerator() ) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if( this.getNumerator() > other.getNumerator() ) {
            return 1;
        }
        else return 0;
    }
    else return 1;
}

public String toString() {
    return this.numerator + "/" + this.denominator + "\n";
```

}
}

this is the runner

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
public class RationalRunner {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Rational test = new Rational();
    out.println("test = " + test);
    Rational newOne = new Rational(3, 4);
    out.println("newOne = " + newOne);
    out.println("test.equals(newOne) = " + test.equals(newOne));
    newOne = (Rational) test.clone();
    out.println("\n\nnewOne after test.clone() = " + newOne);
    out.println("test.equals(newOne) = " + test.equals(newOne));

    Rational rOne = new Rational(1, 2);
    Rational rTwo = new Rational(2, 3);
    out.println("1/2.equals(2/3) = " + rOne.equals(rTwo));
    test.setRational(4, 6);
    out.println("2/3.equals(4/6) = " + rTwo.equals(test));

    out.println("\n\nrOne = " + rOne);
    out.println("rTwo = " + rTwo);
    out.println("rOne.compareTo(rTwo) = " + rOne.compareTo(rTwo));
    out.println("rTwo.compareTo(rOne) = " + rTwo.compareTo(rOne));
    rOne.add(rTwo);
    out.println("\n\nrOne.add(rTwo) = " + rOne);
    rOne.setRational(1, 2);
    rTwo.setRational(1, 3);
    rOne.add(rTwo);
    out.println("\n\n1/2.add(1/3) = " + rOne);

    rOne.setRational(4, 10);
    rTwo.setRational(3, 5);
    rOne.add(rTwo);
    out.println("\n\n4/10.add(3/5) = " + rOne);
    rOne.setRational(2, 10);
    rTwo.setRational(3, 6);
    rOne.add(rTwo);
    out.println("\n\n2/10.add(3/6) = " + rOne);
    //1/4 + 2/8 = 1/2
    rOne.setRational(1, 4);
    rTwo.setRational(2, 8);
    out.println("\n\n1/4.equals(2/8) = " + rOne.equals(rTwo));
    rOne.add(rTwo);
    out.println("\n\n1/4.add(2/8) = " + rOne);

    //1/6 + 2/8 = 5/12
    rOne.setRational(1, 6);
    rTwo.setRational(2, 8);
    out.println("\n\n1/6.equals(2/8) = " + rOne.equals(rTwo));
    rOne.add(rTwo);
    out.println("\n\n1/6.add(2/8) = " + rOne);
}
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the error?

Comment: there is no error occurring, but it's the wrong output.  The lab is supposed to take in a "fraction" where a new Rational(int a, int b); a is the numerator and b is the denominator.

Comment: for example, when you set one of them to 1/6 and 2/8, it comes up with 14/48 when it should be 20/48. I have tried retyping the add method and trying a different way, but it still comes out with the 14/48, im not sure why

Comment: @MaxwellGilbert: Please update your expectation and clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example, when you set one of them to 1/6 and 2/8, it comes up with 14/48 when it should be 20/48. I have tried retyping the add method and trying a different way, but it still comes out with the 14/48, im not sure why

As your example, when i comment out `.equals()` method, it return the correct value.
So, i check your `.compareTo()` method and find out, you reduce on raw data. It's means after compare, the value of `rOne` and `rTwo` was modified.

You should clone object and calculate on them

> ```
>     Rational num1 = new Rational(numerator, denominator);
>     Rational num2 = new Rational(other.getNumerator(), other.getDenominator());
> ```

I've correct them:

```
  public int compareTo(Rational other) {
  //Should create copy constructor
    Rational num1 = new Rational(numerator, denominator);
    Rational num2 = new Rational(other.getNumerator(), other.getDenominator());
    num1.reduce();
    num2.reduce();

    if (num1.getDenominator() < num2.getDenominator()) {
      return -1;
    } else if (num1.getDenominator() == num2.getDenominator()) {
      if (num1.getNumerator() < num2.getNumerator()) {
        return -1;
      } else if (num1.getNumerator() > num2.getNumerator()) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  }
```

P/s: I just check with your example. So any calculator is wrong, you can correct on the same way.

Comment: @MaxwellGilbert: to make your code more readable. You can reduce if/else on `compareTo` after `return` statement.